# @TempDir created has null value in JUnit5

Tags: junit5

I am trying to create temp folder, add files to it and iterate over the files, in one of my test cases. I am currently using Junit5's @TempDir annotation.

`@TempDir Path tempDir2;`

Further when I tried to create a file in the temp folder, I found that the path of dir is showing null.
It should have been actually created in /tmp folder as per my knowledge.
Any idea anyone, what could be the cause for tempDir path to be null?

Comment: You’ll have to show us a full example - including imports - so that others can replicate your problem. Without that the space of possibilities is too large to solve the riddle.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the reason why TempDir is null is that because you have imported the wrong Test class.

This is the class you need to use: `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`.

TempDir won't work with `org.junit.Test`!

Comment: I have only org.junit.jupiter and it still does not work